# How to import a stenciljs component into another project configured with require?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, tsconfig, stenciljs

I've developed a sample stencil component to use in my existing project and it has all dependencies loaded through require js. I'm unable to import to existing project.

I've tried different configurations with `module` value `amd`, `commonjs`, and with target `es3`, `es5` in stencil project's `tsconfig.json`, but none of them seemed to work.

After stencil build, the `dist` folder structure is as follows:

```
+ cjs
+ collection
+ esm
+ fonts
+ icons
+ index.js
+ loader
+ types
+ my-component.json
+ my-component
   - fvhzbl6z.entry.js
   - fvhzbl6z.es5.entry.js
   - fvhzbl6z.sc.entry.js
   - fvhzbl6zsc.es5.entry.js
   - my-component.abuimksq.js
   - my-component.u8wgqi9a.js
+ my-component.js         /* I'm trying to import this file */
```

I've tried copying the `my-component` folder and `my-component.js` to a separate folder and referenced `my-component.js` in a sample html file and it worked. But importing this to existing project is throwing errors.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'lib/bluebird',
    'lib/mycomponent/my-component'
],
function (
    $,
    Promise,
    MyComponent
) {
    'use strict';

    /* some stuff here */

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

`Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
Error: Parse error using esprima for file: /Users/sudouser/Downloads/jsproject/dist/tmp/js/lib/stencilcomponent/my-component/fvhzbl6z.entry.js
Error: Line 1: Unexpected token
In module tree:
    app`